# R data.table: names of .SD not available for assignment

Tags: r, data.table

Often, I want to manipulate several variables in a DT and I need to select the column names based on their names or class.

```
d <- data.table(x = 1:10, y= letters[1:10])

# My usual approach
col <- str_subset(names(d), '^x')
d[, (col) := 2:11]
```

However, it would be very useful and less verbose to do this:

```
 d[, (names(.SD)) := 2:11, .SDcols = patterns('^x')]
```

But this throws an error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(d, , `:=`((names(.SD)), 2:11), .SDcols = patterns("^x")) : 
  LHS of := isn't column names ('character') or positions ('integer' or 'numeric')
>
```

The column names of .SD are available, though:

```
> d[, names(.SD), .SDcols = patterns('^x')]
[1] "x"
```

Why aren't the names of .SD available for assignment on the LHS of :=?

Comment: this is a long-standing feature request: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/795; if you're feeling adventurous, there's an unmerged pull request implementing the feature, early testing would be helpful https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/4163

Comment: Thanks Michael for the information. I'm not up to it, I'm afraid. Let me just say that I would very much welcome to see this new feature go through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted this is not yet possible. The workaround only adds one line of code:

```
cols = grep('^x', names(d))
d[ , (cols) := 2:11, .SDcols = cols]
```

Comment: Do you know of any progress on this feature? It is still not possible in the current version, but the github logs seem auspicious, and it would be very convenient.